# How can i create an environment whose cuda virsion is different with the ubuntu system?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I need to work with tensorflow and pytorch. Pytorch need cuda9.0 however tensorflow need cuda10.0, so how can i create a environment with cuda10.0 on a cuda9.0 system environment?

Is there any possible that I can specify cuda PATH when I create a new environment.

when I create a new environment, something is wrong with my environment variables, but it also give me some hint if i can change the environment variables in different environments.

```
  environment variables:
            ALL_PROXY=<set>
             CIO_TEST=<not set>
           CONDA_ROOT=/home/lz/anaconda3
        DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
      LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:
       MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
             NO_PROXY=<set>
                 PATH=/home/lz/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/lz/.local/bin:/usr/lo
                      cal/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/
                      local/games:/snap/bin
   REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
```

Comment: why do you say something is wrong with the environment variables ad you have set them?

Comment: No, I didn't set them. failure message is " ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://127.0.0.1:1080/" ,so may be it wasn't the environment variables.

Comment: Looks like a SOCKS/HTTP proxy error. Not really related to CUDA?